# Image upload not received

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I am getting the `img_description` but my `img_name` remain empty.

Basic php code

```
$msg = "";

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
$target = "images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']); // get error here

$image = $_FILES['image']['name']; // get error here
$text = $_POST['text'];

$sql = "INSERT into images (img_name, img_description) values ('$image', '$text')";

$smt = $heidisql->prepare($sql);
$smt->execute();

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) { //error here
    $msg = "Image upload sucessfully";
 }else {
   $msg = "Image failed to upload properly";
 }
```

My basic Form

```
 <form method="POST" action="checkout.php" enctype="multipart/form-date">
     <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
     <div>
       <input type="file" name="image">
     </div>

     <div>
        <textarea name="text" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="img text decription" ></textarea>
     </div>

      <div>
         <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload img">
      </div>

   </form>
```

**Table:** images, attribute -> img_id, img_name, img_description

> **Error:** Undefined index: image

Comment: You have a typo in the `enctype` in your form tag: `multipart/form-date` <= It should be `multipart/form-data`

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Do you have 'file_uploads = On' in your php.ini file?

Comment: This is just a very basic example, I am learning how to insert img, in my actual code I will use prepared statement, tys by the way it work!

Comment: No problem. Just a suggestion. Always make sure that your code is safe and secure (even when you do tests and examples). At some point, your code will be turned into real code and you will forget to refactor some parts. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: @fyrye - Please check the code. The OP _isn't_ storing the actual files in the DB, only the file names.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I had, though the title is misleading, which was the reason for my comment leading with `For all intents and purposes` for others who came here based on the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the `enctype` in your form tag.

Change

```
multipart/form-date
```

to

```
multipart/form-data
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a write mistake **enctype="multipart/form-date"** use **enctype="multipart/form-data"** instead.